# Copying an instance of a model and updating fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to copy an instance of my Page model and set the new page's status to "draft." This code works perfectly in the Django shell, but in the admin action where it lives, a new instance is created but the status is not updated.

```
for page in pages:
        page.pk, page.id = None, None
        page.save()
        page.status = Page.DRAFT
        page.updated_at = datetime.now()
        page.save(force_update=True)
```

So the above code creates a new page, but does not change its status.

I think it might have something to do with Page having proxy models depending on the status (PublishedPage, DraftPage, etc.) I'm not sure what the problem is, though.

Comment: Why `page.save()` before all the attributes are set?

Comment: I was just trying to make sure that I didn't save a model with no primary key.

Comment: "didn't save a model with no primary key?"  Django's ORM creates the keys for you when they don't exist.  And does an update when the do exist.

Comment: Your code above works for me. Could you post the source for your `Page` model?

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

```
for page in pages:
    new_page= Page.objects.create(
        this= page.this, that=page.that, ...
        status= Page.DRAFT )
```

Much simpler.  Much clearer.  And it actually works.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I wouldn't have to change this code if the schema of Page changed.

Comment: @tocf: "wouldn't have to change this code if the schema of Page changed"  That's unachievable in general.  The idea of minimizing code changes an attractive nuisance.  Schema changes always lead to code changes.  Otherwise, why bother changing the schema?

Comment: Yeah, but the model also has a _lot_ of fields.

Comment: @tocf:  So?  Today you copy and paste the list of fields from the model.  Once.  In the future you add fields as your schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the proxy models subclassing Page had custom save method overriding my updates.